# Query executed and email is sent even though JavaScript alert box Cancel button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

**Greeting everyone,**

I am having a problem in which my database is updated and the email is sent even though I clicked on the Cancel button of the alert box. The alert box is generated using JavaScript onclick Event. The email is sent using PHPMailer. I am confused whether this is the PHP code having problem or is it the JavaScript onclick event having problem. If it is the JavaScript onclick event problem, is it possible for me to not use any JQuery or Bootstrap modal box for the alert box?

**Here are my codes for the PHP part:**

```
<?php
  //Condition when the submit button is clicked
  if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])){
    try 
    {
      $appointment_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['appointment_date']));

      // Inserting the data into database
      $smt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO appointment (appointment_type, appointment_date, appointment_time, student_id, lecturer_id, field, venue, remarks, appointment_status)
                          VALUES (:appointment_type, :appointment_date, :appointment_time, :student_id, :lecturer_id, :field, :venue, :remarks, :appointment_status)");

      $smt->bindParam(':appointment_type',  $_POST["appointment_type"]);
      $smt->bindParam(':appointment_date', $appointment_date);
      $smt->bindParam(':appointment_time', $_POST["appointment_time"]);
      $smt->bindParam(':student_id', $_POST["student_id"]);
      $smt->bindParam(':lecturer_id', $_POST["lecturer_id"]);
      $smt->bindParam(':field', $_POST["field_id"]);
      $smt->bindParam(':venue', $_POST["venue"]);
      $smt->bindParam(':remarks', $_POST["remarks"]);
      $smt->bindParam(':appointment_status', $_POST["appointment_status"]);

      //PHPMailer set up 
      $stulec_link = "http://localhost/stulec/index.php";     
      $output="<strong>Greetings from STULEC,</strong> <br/>
              <p>There is an appointment request from " . $_POST['student_name'] . " who is currently studying in the " . $_POST['programme'] . " programme. </p>
              The appointment details are such as below: <br/>
                <ul>
                  <li>Appointment Type: ". $_POST['appointment_type'] ."</li>
                  <li>Appoinment Date: ". $_POST['appointment_date'] ."</li>
                  <li>Appointment Time: ". $_POST['appointment_time'] ."</li>
                  <li>Venue: ". $_POST['venue'] ." </li>
                  <li>Course Field: ". $_POST['field_name'] ." </li>
                  <li>Remarks: ". $_POST['remarks'] . "</li>
                </ul>
              </p>
              <p>Please approve the appointment request by logging in into <a href='".$stulec_link."'>STULEC</a>. Thank you.</p>";

      $mail = new PHPMailer;
      $mail->isSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
      $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                   // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username = EMAIL;              // SMTP username
      $mail->Password = PASS;               // SMTP password
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                    // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
      $mail->Port = 587;                        // TCP port to connect to

      $mail->setFrom('stulec@edu.my', 'STULEC');  //From sender
      $mail->addAddress( $_POST['lect_email'] , $_POST['lect_name']);  // Add a recipient
      $mail->isHTML(true);                    // Set email format to HTML

      $mail->Subject = 'STULEC | Appointment Request from Student';
      $mail->Body    =  $output;
      $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
      $mail->ContentType = 'text/html';                          

      if (($smt->execute()) && $mail->send())
      {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('An appointment request has been sent to the lecturer. Please wait until the lecturer responds to your request.');";
        echo 'window.location= "student-view-pending-appointment.php"';
        echo "</script>";
      }                                          
      else
      {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: The appoinment cannot be made!');";
        echo 'window.location= "student-appointment-form.php"';
        echo "</script>";
      }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

?>
```

**Here are my code at the button part:**

```
 <!--Submit button-->
                  <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="checkConfirm()">Submit</button>
                  </div>
```

**Here are my code at the JavaScript part:**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      //Script for confirmation
      function checkConfirm()
      {
          return confirm('Are you sure you want to make an appointment with this lecturer?');
      }
    </script>
```

Please guide me on how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: With this type of “old-school” event handling, you need to pass the return value along from “within” the onclick attribute: `onclick="return checkConfirm()"`

Comment: Move your `onclick` to form's `onsubmit`. Also add `return checkConfirm()`

Comment: @04FS thank you for pointing out. the problem was because I did not put "return"

Comment: @Justinas: Thank you as well. I did not put the onclick on the form submit. I just missed out the return word in the button part.